# No consigo hacer un codigo para cambiar estado de led de parpadeo a fijo en Raspberry pi Pico con CircuitPython

Tags: python, raspberry

estoy intentando escribir un codigo (o más bien hacer un franskenstein, dado que no tengo conocimientos como para escribir yo como tal) para conseguir lo siguiente:

Al pulsar el botón:
-Se reproduce un audio
-El led se pone a parpadear
Al volver a pulsar el botón:
-El led queda fijo
-El audio se pausa (esto es opcional y ahora mismo lo he dejado de lado)
Al volver a pulsar el boton:
-El led vuelve a parpadear

Y así sucesivamente.
De momento consigo que el primer paso lo haga bien, despues vuelvo a pulsar el botón y el led se queda fijo, pero solo mientras el boton esté pulsado, en cuanto lo suelto sigue parpadeando.

Os dejo el codigo a ver si me podeis echar una mano:

```
import time
import board
import digitalio
import audiomp3
import audiopwmio

led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP14)
led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
button = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP17)
button.switch_to_input(pull=digitalio.Pull.DOWN)
audio = audiopwmio.PWMAudioOut(board.GP0)
decoder = audiomp3.MP3Decoder(open("sample.mp3", "rb"))

while True:
    if button.value:
        audio.play(decoder, loop=True)
        while audio.playing:
            if button.value:
                led.value = True
            else:
                led.value = True
                time.sleep(0.5)
                led.value = False
                time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Problema 1: No haces *debouncing*. La variable `button.value` cambia de valor aleatoriamente mientras presionas y sueltas el botón.

Comment: Problema 2: El botón es un pulsador y lo que necesitas es un *conmutador* (toogle switch); algo que permanezca en su posición luego de pulsarlo. No es el valor actual de `button.value` lo que manda, si que valor tenía a la última pulsación.

Comment: ¿Como hago debouncing? La verdad es que no tengo ni idea... Se que lo ideal para la luz seria un interruptor en vez de un pulsador, pero hay que hacerlo con un pulsador, es lo que hay...

Comment: El elemento físico es un pulsador, pero el código lo convierte en un conmutador. Mantienes una variable lógica que cambia de estado cada vez que presiona el pulsador.